# how to filter api with antd rangepicker

Tags: reactjs, antd

I've been struggling to filter my data using rangepicker from antd. I was able to filter using the select components and it works as expected. The date in my data is a string because its dummy data for the moment. Eventually, i'll have to intro a api.

I thought because its a string it would work like the others but the range picker, doesn't do anything. Am i missing something?

Data

```
export const Employees = [
    {
        name: "jane",
        skill: 'java',
        rankgrade: '44.2',
        available:'08/10/2023',
        doj:'14/04/21'
    },
]
```

state

```
const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = useState("");
  const [selectSkills, setSelectSkills] = useState("");
```

filtering with select

```
<RangePicker
              
               format={"DD-MM-YYYY"}
               
               onChange={(value)  => setSelectValue(value)}
              />
               
              </Space>

              <Space wrap>
                <Select
                  defaultValue={selectRankGrade}
                  style={{ width: 120 }}
                  onChange={(value)  => setSelectRankGrade(value) }
                  options={Employees.map((grade) => {
                    return {
                      label: `${grade.rankgrade}`,
                      value: grade.rankgrade,
                    };
                  })}
                />
              </Space>


{Employees.filter(
                (employee) =>
                  
                  employee.available === selectValue
                  && 
                  employee.rankgrade === selectRankGrade
                  &&
                  employee.skill === selectSkills 
                  &&
                  employee.name !== "" 
                  &&
                  employee.doj != "" 
                  
              )
              .map((filteredPerson) => (
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td className="col-lg-2">{filteredPerson.name}</td>
                    <td className="col-lg-2">{filteredPerson.rankgrade}</td>
                    <td className="col-lg-2">{filteredPerson.skill}</td>
                    <td className="col-lg-2">{filteredPerson.available}</td>
                    <td className="col-lg-2">{filteredPerson.doj}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              ))}
            </table>
```